# How to bind a TabItem Header to a TextBox in FrameworkElementFactory?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I tried to create a `TabItem` with a `TextBox` in it from [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/035f7878-c577-486d-8561-3d193bb21fbe/ho-to-allow-the-user-to-edit-the-tab-header-?forum=wpf).

I found out that the `TabItem` Header is NOT bind to the `TextBox`.

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TabItem ti = new TabItem();
    DataTemplate tabItemTemplate = new DataTemplate();

    tabItemTemplate.DataType = typeof(TabItem);
    FrameworkElementFactory textBoxFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
    textBoxFactory.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("."));
    textBoxFactory.SetValue(NameProperty, "textBox");
    textBoxFactory.SetValue(BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(0));
    //textBoxFactory.SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, false);
    tabItemTemplate.VisualTree = textBoxFactory;
    ti.Header = "Test!";
    ti.HeaderTemplate = tabItemTemplate;
    ti.MouseDoubleClick += TabItem_MouseDoubleClick;
    tabControl.Items.Add(ti);
}

private void TabItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show((sender as TabItem).Header.ToString());
}
```

[image]
[image]

Could somebody please be so kind and teach me how to bind it correctly?

Much appreciated!

Comment: I must say what you are doing is not nice. You should write XAML code. using the FrameworkElementFactory is not recommended. It also makes writing UI code so much more difficult - difficult to write and difficult to read.

Comment: @BionicCode It worked! Thanks trillions! Could you please be so kind and post it as an answer so I could mark it as the best answer? Much appreciated!

Comment: @BionicCode I'm new to WPF, so I don't really know the difference! Could you please be so kind and tell me why it is "not nice" and "not recommended"? Much appreciated!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory?view=net-5.0#remarks : **Remarks**
This class is a deprecated way to programmatically create templates, which are subclasses of FrameworkTemplate such as ControlTemplate or DataTemplate; not all of the template functionality is available when you create a template using this class. The recommended way to programmatically create a template is to load XAML from a string or a memory stream using the Load method of the XamlReader class.

Comment: @EldHasp OK, I'll go check it out, thanks for your help!

Comment: It's too complicated to implement complex UI e.g. using triggers, templates, VisualStateManager etc. XAML gives you a visual feedback on how your element tree currently looks like: you instantly see relationships like parent and child. It's readable, the C# code is not really readable and therefore difficult to maintain. You can distribute XAML code like templates accross files. Resource management is easier. There are many advantages in favoring XAML over C# when it comes to designing the GUI. Take a look at my answer. I have updated it to show how your C# code looks like in XAML.

Comment: You also have the XAML designer that gives you an instant preview of your GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Binding` configuration is wrong.

`new Binding(".")` is missing the `Binding.Source`.
It should be:

```
var binding = new Binding("Header") { Source = ti };
```

---

### Example of using XAML

The following example replicates your C# code

```
<TabControl>
  <TabItem Header="Test" MouseDoubleClick="TabItem_MouseDoubleClick" >
    <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" 
                 Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}, Path=Header}" />
       </DataTemplate>
     </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
   </TabItem>
 </TabControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Complementing @BionicCode's answer

The problem with your original binding is that you are pointing to the current Data Context.
Your binding is equivalent to an empty Binding "new Binding ();".
Thus, you get a binding not to a property, but to a source (The default source is the current Data Context).
But the binding can only change the property of the source, not the source itself.
The Header template is applied to the contents of the TabItem's Header property.
Therefore, to get the same value, but not as a source of the binding, but as a property in the Path of the binding, you need to go up to the TabItem level.
@BionicCode in his answer showed you examples of such bindings.

I will offer another option for integration into your code:

```cs
        private static readonly DataTemplate headerTemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Parse
            (@"
<DataTemplate xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
              xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'>
    <TextBox x:Name='textBox'
             Text='{Binding Header,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}},
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}'
             BorderThickness='0'/>
</DataTemplate>
            ");

        private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TabItem ti = new TabItem();
            ti.Header = "Test!";
            ti.HeaderTemplate = headerTemplate;
            ti.MouseDoubleClick += TabItem_MouseDoubleClick;
            tabControl.Items.Add(ti);
        }
```